# param info for mojolicious routing using under

Tags: perl, routes, mojolicious

I'm using the `under` method in Mojolicious routing to handle some route permissions. I was hoping to handle nearly all routes by passing to a common controller function, however it doesn't appear that `under` captures all of the params that I need.  Here's a MWE:

```
package Test;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious', -signatures;

sub startup ($app) {
  my $config = $app->plugin('NotYAMLConfig');
  $app->secrets($config->{secrets});

  $app->routes->under('/api')->to('Permission#allow')->get('/users/:user_id')->to('User#getUser');
  $app->routes->under('/api/other/users/:user_id')->to('Permission#allow')->get('/')->to('User#getUser');
}
1;
```

with the module `Permission` as:

```
package Test::Controller::Permission;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller', -signatures;

sub allow ($c) {
  print $c->dumper($c->stash->{'mojo.captures'});
  return 1;
}
1;
```

and module `User.pm` is:

```
package Test::Controller::User;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller', -signatures;

sub getUser ($c) {
  $c->render(text => 'The user_id is: ' . $c->param('user_id'));
}
1;
```

There is a basic script called `test` that was created with the `mojo generate` and running `script/test /api/users/3` shows that the `user_id` is not available as a `$c->param('user_id')` in the `Permission#allow` sub, however is in the `User#getUser` sub.

Running `script/test /api/other/users/3` does show that now `Permission#allow` has `user_id` available as a param.

This is clearly the difference in defining the `under` part of the route.  My question is do I need to defined all of the `under` in my routes (I have about 20 in my full app), or is there another way to capture the params in a more general way.

I have noticed that the `allow` sub has the url of the full route (with the route params).

Comment: You can get to the data of the next dispatch cycle with `$c->match->stack->[1]->{user_id}` in your Permission class. Any reason not to use URL params? [documentation](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Under)